# Не соответствие результатов на сайте (Warmup-1 > delDel) и в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java

День добрый. Только начинаю разбираться в `Java` и тут такая непонятка. На многим известном сайте тренировочных примеров есть задачка

> Given a string, if the string "del" appears starting at index 1, return a string where that "del" has been deleted. Otherwise, return the string unchanged.

Я недолго думая пишу

```
public String delDel(String str) {
    if (str.contains("del")) {
        return str.replaceAll("del", "");
    } else return str;
}
```

При этом получая странные результаты, а именно:

> 1. delDel("abcdel") → "abcdel" "abc"(вот тут не допечатывает, я так понимаю, двойную кавычку)  X

> delDel("del") → "del"   ""(и тут также не допечатывает, я так понимаю, двойную кавычку) X

> 2. delDel("aadelbb") → "aadelbb"   "aabb"(тут вообще теряется bb") X

При всем этом если забиваю все в `IntelliJ IDEA` первая непонятка выдает нужную строку, а вторая не теряет `bb"`
В идею забивал для наглядности (меняя строку `str`).

```
String str = "aadelbb";
if (str.contains("del")) {
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("del", ""));
} else System.out.println(str);
```

Заранее спасибо за ваше мнение.

Comment: Непонятно при чем тут двойные кавычки и где кто их не допечатывает. Напишите консольный тест, приведите его код и вывод в консоль с подробным описанием проблемы.

Comment: Я не очень понятно наверно поставил вопрос.  Есть сайт https://codingbat.com/prob/p100905 на котором если забьете мой код (верхний) 
 то увидите ошибки, а если забить этот же код (нижний) в идею, то идея выдает другие резалты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно поняли задание. Нужно заменить строку `del` тогда и только тогда когда она начинается на индексе 1 входной строки, т.е. для входной строки "abcdel" метод должен вернуть входную строку без изменений.

Ваш же метод заменяет все вхождения `del` где бы они не находились. Из-за этого и возникают ошибки.

Из-за непонимания условия, Вы также неправильно поняли сообщения о непройденных тестах:

> delDel("abcdel") → "abcdel" "abc"(вот тут не допечатывает, я так понимаю, двойную кавычку) X

Нет, здесь говорится, что метод должен был вернуть "abcdel", а вернул "abc".

Выделенная красным кавычка означает, что в конце строки должно было быть что-то еще ("del" после "abc"). Сайт пытается помочь подсвечивая разницу между ожидаемым и полученным результатом.

> delDel("aadelbb") → "aadelbb" "aabb"(тут вообще теряется bb") X

Аналогично, "bb" подсвечивается потому, что в строке здесь ошибка: вместо "bb" должно было быть "delbb".

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Мне физичка еще говорила -"Правильно прочитанное условие задачи - 60 % успеха ее решения"

Comment: @Max Да, пожалуйста! Успехов в учебе и добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Сюдя по заданию метод должен быть реализован немного по-другому:

```
public String delDel(String str) {
    if (str.indexOf("del", 1) == 1){
        return str.replaceFirst("del", "");
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу. Но вопрос не в том как решить. Вариантов может быть "хоть отбавляй". Вопрос в том почему не работает предложенный мной вариант и почему разные результаты на сайте и в идее.